# Converting all .haml files in a dir to .html in another dir

Tags: haml

In a simple website I'm working on, I have a directory `haml` and a directory `pages`. The haml folder contains the .haml files I work on, and the pages folder contains my converted .html files.

I know I can convert the files, from the website root directory, by doing:

`haml haml/about.haml pages/about.html` for each file.

However, is there a way to convert all the .haml files in my haml folder to an equivalent .html file in the pages folder?

Something like: `haml haml/*.haml html/*.html`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice [html2haml](https://github.com/haml/html2haml) gem for this purpose

and you can run it on a directory using

```
find . -name \*.erb -print | sed 'p;s/.erb$/.haml/' | xargs -n2 html2haml
```

Comment: OP wanted to convert haml to html and not the other way around

Answer (score 1):

guard watches `haml` files, compiles them, you can set an output dir as well.

https://github.com/guard/guard-haml sounds like an option.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [python script](https://github.com/mrjoelkemp/haml2html) that sounds like it will do exactly what you want...

I haven't tested it, but per the README, it sounds like it's as simple as:

`python haml2html.py [input_dir] [output_dir]`